# How to handle login with MongoDB through REST API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, vue.js

I'm not sure how to check if the values match with the MongoDB data. I am using `PUT` and trying to use `findOneAndUpdate` to check if the values match.

```
<script>
const logindetails = new Vue({
el: '#logindetails',
data: {

    email: "",
    password: "",
    on: Boolean
},

methods: {
    login: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const log = {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
        }

        const options = {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(log)
        };

       fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/${this.email}/${this.password}', 
options).then(response => {

[...]

</script>
```

This is the server code (it successfully connected to MongoDB) :

```
app.put('/students/:email/:password', (req, res, next) => {
console.log("login");
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
db.collection('users').findOne({email: (req.params.email), password: (req.params.password)},
    {$set: {on: true}})
    .then(results => res.send(results))
    .catch(err => res.send(err))
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't think it is a good idea to put your username and password as query string, because it hurts the restful api convention. It wouldn't make sense to use a put request if there is no body being pass. Also, a post request would make more sense in a login situation .Anyway I digress, here are the usual steps to doing authentication.

**1. (Client-Side) Send the email and password in the body of the fetch request**

```
//something like this

const body = { email, password };
  const response = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:5000/authentication/login",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }
  );
```

2.**(Server-Side - *make sure you to use app.use(express.json()) to access req.body*)**

```
//defining middleware to access req.body

app.use(express.json());

app.post("/authentication/login", async(req,res) =>{
    //1. destructure email and password

    const {email, password} = req.body

    //2. check if user doesn't exist

    const user = await db.user.find({user_email: email})
    if(!user){
        return res.status(401).send("User does not exist");
    }

    //3. Check if password is the same as the password in the database

    if(password !== user.password){
        return res.status(401).send("Wrong Credential")
    }

    //4. This is up to you when the user is authenticated

    res.json(`Welcome back ${email}`);
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to help me. I really appreciate it. I tried running the code but there is an error on the client page which says 'await is only valid in async function'

Comment: Have you use async and await before? Basically , the only way to use await is to set the function as async  Ex. async(req,res) . I do want to remind you that the code above is more of a guideline. Remember db.user will only work if you have the collection user

Comment: Yes I did change the code to the appropriate collection name for my project. Oh ok so I need to set the async(req,res) in the client side? Do I need to do something like this  .then(async response => {

Comment: not on (req,res), because that is only for the backend . You would have to use async for whatever function is using the await keyword . If you are still confuse with the concept of async and await then check out this article => https://dev.to/shoupn/javascript-fetch-api-and-using-asyncawait-47mp

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I must appreciate you accepting my answer; however I am much more concern if you understand what my answer mean. I think Authentication is quite a complicated topic. I suggest you learn about promises and using the fetch request first. Here a good tutorial to get you started  => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoRJizFvM7s

Comment: And here a nice tutorial about fetch => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuEtnrL9-H0 . Good luck

Comment: Yes, I find authentication the most difficult part in coding, I find it so hard to understand but will try my best. Thank you so much for providing the links, it means a lot to me. Thank you so much Sir.